# Form Validation with Jhipster

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, jhipster

My JHipster generator version is: `generator-jhipster 2.27.1`

I am using `show-validation` for my Form validation. Everything seems to be working alright except the following scenario.

1. Assume I have a text field which is `required`.
2. Enter one character, Field becomes valid.
3. Delete the text, Field becomes Invalid, error message appears and the form-group for input turns red.
4. Now Re-enter text. Field becomes valid and error message disappears, but the
   `has-error` class on form-group is not yet removed. Form group still remains red.
5. When you proceed to enter the
   second character, the `has-error` is now removed.

This is the relevant code from **form.directive.js**

```
$inputs.each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    scope.$watch(function() {                               
       return $input.hasClass('ng-invalid') && $input.hasClass('ng-dirty');
    }, function(isInvalid) {
       $formGroup.toggleClass('has-error', isInvalid);
    }); 
}
```

The form-validation directive is not updating immediately but is behind by one input change. I am not able to figure out which part of the code needs modifying.

Added console logs, but to no avail. I assume it has got something to do with text value vis-a-vis model value, but don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

(added: attrs, formCtrl attr to link function and changed $watch.function - uncomment dirty check if needed)

```
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
            element.find('.form-group').each(function() {
                var $formGroup = $(this);
                var $inputs = $formGroup.find('input[ng-model],textarea[ng-model],select[ng-model]');

                if ($inputs.length > 0) {
                    $inputs.each(function() {
                        var $input = $(this);
                        scope.$watch(function() {
                            //inputs need to have 'name' attribute for this to work
                            return formCtrl[$input[0].name].$invalid;
                           //&& formCtrl[$input[0].name].$dirty;
                        }, function(isInvalid) {
                            $formGroup.toggleClass('has-error', isInvalid);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```